# SQL Server get path with recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to get the path for each department with this format 1.1, 1.2 and so on.
This is my department table :

```
id  name    parentId
--------------------
1   Dep 1   0
2   Dep 2   1
3   Dep 3   0
4   Dep 4   1
5   Dep 5   4
6   Dep 6   2
```

This is my recursive CTE that give me the parents and children in a flat table starting from a root department.

```
WITH recursiveCte (parentId, id, name, Level)
AS
(
    -- Anchor member definition
    SELECT 
        d.parentId, d.id, d.name, 
        0 AS Level
    FROM
        Department AS d
    WHERE 
        parentId = 0 

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member definition
    SELECT 
        d.parentId, d.id, d.name,
        Level + 1
    FROM 
        Department AS d
    INNER JOIN 
        recursiveCte AS r ON d.parentId = r.id
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT parentId,id, name, Level
FROM recursiveCte 
ORDER BY id
```

Current results:

```
parentId    id  name    Level
-------------------------------
0           1   Dep 1   0
1           2   Dep 2   1
0           3   Dep 3   0
1           4   Dep 4   1
4           5   Dep 5   2
2           6   Dep 6   2
```

Desired results:

```
parentId    id  name    Level   Path
--------------------------------------
0           1   Dep 1   0       1  
1           2   Dep 2   1       1.1 
2           6   Dep 6   2       1.1.1
1           4   Dep 4   1       1.2
4           5   Dep 5   2       1.2.1 
0           3   Dep 3   0       2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working solution.  It is difficult to describe in words why this works, so I recommend taking apart the query to see how it works yourself.  Basically, we recursively build the path string you want to see, using `ROW_NUMBER` to keep track to which particular parent each new path addition belongs.

```
recursiveCte (parentId, id, name, Level, Path, FullPath) AS (
    SELECT d.parentId, d.id, d.name, 0 AS Level,
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.id) AS nvarchar(max)),
        RIGHT('000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.id) AS nvarchar(max)), 3)
    FROM Department AS d
    WHERE parentId = 0 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT d.parentId, d.id, d.name, r.Level + 1,
        r.Path + '.' +
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.Level ORDER BY d.id) AS nvarchar(max)),
        r.FullPath + '.' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (PARTITION BY r.Level ORDER BY d.id) AS nvarchar(max)), 3)
    FROM Department AS d
    INNER JOIN recursiveCte AS r
        ON d.parentId = r.id
)

SELECT parentId, id, name, Level, Path, FullPath
FROM recursiveCte
ORDER BY FullPath;
```

[image]

### Demo

**Edit:**

I slightly edited my original answer so that it now sorts the path string using a fixed-width version, i.e. every number has a fixed width of 3 digits.  This means that `001` will always sort before `010`, which is the behavior we want.

Comment: I will modifiy the code a little bit cause path 10 will come before path 2 since it's a string.

Comment: @lory I updated my answer so that it now uses a fixed-width version of the path string to do the ordering.  In this case, I assume you won't have any path element greater than 999, but you can easily modify this as you want.