# SQL server table with recursive folder paths

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table of documents and folders that I want to turn into a list of paths but the tables look like this

```
DocumentId, Name, IsFolder
1, Test.doc, 0
2, Test2.doc, 0
3, FolderA, -1
4, Test3.doc, 0
5, FolderB, -1
6, SubFolder1, -1
7, SubFolder2, -1
```

and another table with relationships in

```
ChildId, ParentId
1, 6
2, 6
4, 7
6, 3
7, 5
```

So, I want to have an output of the documents like this

```
Document, Path
Test.doc, FolderA\SubFolder1
Test2.doc, FolderA\SubFolder1
Test3.doc, FolderB\SubFolder2
```

Is it possible to recursively loop though each document and make a string that becomes the full folder path for that document?

Comment: Yes, you're looking for a `recursive cte` such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893656/sql-server-get-path-with-recursive-cte or https://stevestedman.com/2012/02/generating-a-tree-path-with-a-cte/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server get path with recursive CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893656/sql-server-get-path-with-recursive-cte)

Comment: I think we're missing something here. I either see no relationship between your first table and your second, or no relationship between the second and itself. Both are required.

Comment: @Larnu I think the naming is backwards, or roots are tips.. "parent id 1 (testdoc) has child id 6 (subfolder1), parent id 6 (subfolder1) has child id 3 (folderA), parent id 3 has no child.. so the path is collected from R to L, and a parent labelled thing is what the world would call a child and vice versa "

Comment: @Caius Jard That looks like it might be along the right lines but I don't have a parent id in my documents table, just another table that has the relationships in.

Comment: @feijoc that's what a JOIN is for

Comment: @Larnu Sorry I had child/parent field names the wrong way around, have updated.

Comment: @Caius Jard ok will see what I can do with this thanks, have not used a CTE before.

Comment: First get your data into one "table" with `WITH onetable AS( SELECT ... docs JOIN relationships..)`, and then you can apply the recursive CTE advices to your onetable, joining it to itself and concatting the paths together as you go. The stevestedman blog might actually be more helpful than the linked SO question btw (get your onetable CTE to look like their equipment list with an id, a name and a parent). Or just wait, and someone will post the answer here (I'd do it, but really got my hands full at the moment, sorry!), but having a crack will be a useful learning exercise

Comment: Also worth pointing out that you might well have used a CTE, if you ever wrote `WITH (... query...)` to make a query into an alias you can use in another query.. The magic comes when the query inside the WITH refers to itself, and that's the "recursive" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CTE as below:

```
DECLARE @Documents TABLE (
    DocumentId INT, 
    Name NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    IsFolder BIT
)
INSERT @Documents
VALUES
(1, 'Test.doc', 0)
,(2, 'Test2.doc', 0)
,(3, 'FolderA', -1)
,(4, 'Test3.doc', 0)
,(5, 'FolderB', -1)
,(6, 'SubFolder1', -1)
,(7, 'SubFolder2', -1)
DECLARE @Relation TABLE (
    ParentId INT,
    ChildId INT
)
INSERT @Relation
VALUES
(1, 6)
,(2, 6)
,(4, 7)
,(6, 3)
,(7, 5);
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT D.Name AS Path, D.DocumentId ChildId, D.IsFolder FROM @Documents D 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Relation R2 WHERE R2.ParentId = D.DocumentId)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.Path + '\' + D.Name AS Path, D.DocumentId ChildId, D.IsFolder FROM @Documents D
    CROSS JOIN CTE C
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Relation R WHERE C.ChildId = R.ChildId AND R.ParentId = D.DocumentId) 
)
SELECT Path FROM CTE WHERE CTE.IsFolder = 0
```

Output is like:

```
FolderB\SubFolder2\Test3.doc
FolderA\SubFolder1\Test.doc
FolderA\SubFolder1\Test2.doc
```

Comment: Why is SubFolder2 repeated in your example? The output should be FolderB\SubFolder2\Test3.doc not FolderB\SubFolder2\SubFolder2\Test3.doc