# Recursive CTE with hierarchy data

Tags: sql-server

Sample data:

```
    declare @docs table (docid int, name varchar(10), isfolder int)
    declare @hierarchy table (childid int, parent varchar(10))

    insert @docs values (1, 'Doc1', 0)
    insert @docs values (2, 'Doc2', 0 )
    insert @docs values (3, 'Folder1', 1 )
    insert @docs values (4, 'Folder2', 1 )
    insert @docs values (5, 'SubFolderA', 1 )
    insert @docs values (6, 'SubFolderB', 1 )

    insert @hierarchy values (1, 5)
    insert @hierarchy values (1, 6)
    insert @hierarchy values (2, 6)
    insert @hierarchy values (5, 3)
    insert @hierarchy values (6, 4)
```

I want to list the data above so I end up with the documents (isfolder = 0) and the folder paths that they are in.

Expected output:

```
DocId    Name    Path
--------------------------------------
  1      Doc1    Folder1\SubFolderA
  1      Doc1    Folder2\SubFolderB
  2      Doc2    Folder2\SubFolderB
```

CTE

I started to write this next CTE as it said this can be used to create my output but I am wrong somewhere

```
;WITH folderCTE (docid, name) AS
(
    -- Anchor member
    SELECT docid, CAST(name AS varchar(max)) AS name 
    FROM @docs 
    WHERE isfolder = 0

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member that references expression_name.
    SELECT d.docid, CAST(folderCTE.Name + '\' + d.name AS varchar(max)) AS name
    FROM folderCTE 
    INNER JOIN @docs d ON d.docid = folderCTE.docid
)
-- references expression name
SELECT *
FROM folderCTE
```

Can anyone show me how I should be doing a CTE for this?

Comment: You sure your expected output is right? Doesn't look it!

Comment: How is this question different from your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63010902/sql-server-table-with-recursive-folder-paths where you accepted the answer that you received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a CTE which just expands the hierarchy for folders, and a second one to build the hierarchy, you can simply join to this to get the folder for your docs:

```
declare @docs table (docid int, name varchar(10), isfolder int)
declare @hierarchy table (childid int, parentid varchar(10))

insert @docs values (1, 'Doc1', 0)
insert @docs values (2, 'Doc2', 0 )
insert @docs values (3, 'Folder1', 1 )
insert @docs values (4, 'Folder2', 1 )
insert @docs values (5, 'SubFolderA', 1 )
insert @docs values (6, 'SubFolderB', 1 )
insert @docs values (7, 'SuperFold1', 1 )

insert @hierarchy values (1, 5)
insert @hierarchy values (1, 6)
insert @hierarchy values (2, 6)
insert @hierarchy values (5, 3)
insert @hierarchy values (6, 4)
insert @hierarchy values (3, 7)

;WITH folderCTE 
AS
(
    select docid, cast(name as nvarchar(max)) as name, parentid
    from @docs d
    left join @hierarchy h on d.docid=h.childid
    where d.isfolder = 1
),
folderHierarchyCTE
as
(
    select docid, cast(name  as nvarchar(max)) as name
    from folderCTE where parentid is null
    union all
    select d.docid, cast(p.name + '/' + d.name as nvarchar(max))
    from folderCTE d
    inner join folderHierarchyCTE p on d.parentid = p.docid 
)
SELECT d.docid, d.name, f.name
FROM   @docs d
inner join @hierarchy h on h.childid=d.docid
inner join folderHierarchyCTE f on h.parentid=f.docid
where d.isfolder = 0
```

Comment: Does this work if there are more folder levels? For example, I added `insert @docs values (7, 'SuperFold1', 1 )` and `insert @hierarchy values (3, 7)` which should add an extra level above `Folder1`, but it doesn't actually show this.

Comment: Oh yes you are correct on real data this does not return more than the two levels. This looked like the best solution till I ran it on production.

Comment: @feijoc see update, I added in the extra rows that basodre pointed out to proove this should work with more levels of hierarchy